# get results from entered first name plus last name of a user

Tags: php, mysql

i made a search user system in which user's are searched by their first name or email but the problem is if i enter the full name of the user it does not search it and also i am not able to make a query for that . i used this query to get user from first name and email.

```
"select * from users_profile where fname like '%$q%'  or Email like '%$q%' order by rand() LIMIT 10"
```

but how to get users from both first and second name . suppose i enter `"john"` it gives out the full result such as `john doe` but if i enter the full name such as `john doe` it does not gives any result. in my database the `first name` is represented by `fname` and `last name` by `lname`. ny help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mysql [CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function to concatenate both first and second name and then search on the result, like this:

```
select * from users_profile where CONCAT(fname,' ',lname) like '%$q%'
```

that should do what you want.